# how to display netstat output on nagios

Tags: windows-server-2008, nagios, snmp, netstat, nsclient++

Can you please tell me how to monitor an established connection (on a specified port) in a windows machine from nagios (centOS) here an example (output of netstat):

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
 TCP    192.168.1.96:1551      192.168.1.88:22        ESTABLISHED
[fzsftp.exe]
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can check this over SNMP using something like [check_netstat_snmp](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-Connections,-Stats-and-Bandwidth/check_netstat--2F-check_snmp_netstat/details). It requires the `snmpnetstat` utility, which is one of the standard snmp binaries.